# Tracking windows service status and displaying the status in WPF UI

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, service

I am developing an windows application using WPF and this application follows MVVM. My application displays the status of two Windows services. That is, if the application is open and the service is stopped, immediately the status needs to be changed in UI. Similarly if the application is open and the service is started, immediately the status needs to be changed in Application UI.Before, I never needed to handle windows services. So please help me.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx) class to poll for the service status at intervals.
With this anyway you can't really have an immediate notification, there is a poll delay error. If you want something more accurate you should modify the services to send its status to a listener using some IPC mechanism.

Comment: I do not have any previous experience in Windows Service. If possible, please provide code sample.